# perf_event_open and interval counting

Tags: linux, perf

If I have `perf_event_open(&attr, tid, -1, -1, 0)` with

```
attr.sample_period = _interval; (1ms)
attr.sample_type = PERF_SAMPLE_CALLCHAIN;
```

What does it precisely mean? Does it mean that my registered handler is notified with a callchain when the thread spent exactly 1ms on whatever CPU? If the thread spent 500us on CPU-1 and now reached 500us on CPU-2, then a signal (SIGPROF) is propagated to the process's handler by the same thread running on CPU?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html), it is the stack backtrace (so the function call chain) from the current instruction each time the event period elapses. The *sample_max_stack* field provides the maximum number of frames to store, the *exclude_callchain_user/kernel* fields respectively exclude the user and kernel space frames.

The 3rd parameter passed to *perf_event_open()* decides which cpu to take in account:

```c
int perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *attr,
                           pid_t pid, int cpu, int group_fd,
                           unsigned long flags);
```

As you pass -1 for this parameter:

> pid > 0 and cpu == -1
> This measures the specified process/thread on any CPU.

**N.B.:** On Intel architectures, the Performance Monitoring Unit (PMU) have a feature called Processor Event Based Sampling (PEBS) and a Performance Monitoring Interrupt (PMI) which is triggered on counter overflow conditions. PEBS uses a debug store mechanism and the PMI to store a set of architectural state information for the processor.

This [document](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Sampling_with_perf_record) gives some details about how *perf* operates. The sampling period is expressed in term of number of occurrences of an event, not the number of timer ticks.

This [document](http://web.eece.maine.edu/%7Evweaver/projects/perf_events/sampling/pebs_ibs_sampling.pdf) gives more information about the way sampling is implemented on several hardware architectures.

Comment: Yeap, I've read the documentation. It does not explain how the time is calculated .. across all CPUs together - using some global buffer, per CPU - one thread has buffer on multiple CPU and the time is not collected ... or it behaves differently.

Comment: In my understanding, it is not the time but a counter of events. The Intel PMU counters have the ability to send a interrupt (PMI) each time a counter reaches a given value. So, I guess that perf is based on this mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting articles. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html - sample_period - I understood that passed sample_period is like one event.